# subprocess.run not working in windows - The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to use the subprocess module in visual sutdio code but I keep getting an error. Here is the code:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run("dir")
```

or

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run("dir","/p")
```

and the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\Dropbox (Personal)\My Python\external\extrprg.py", line 2, in <module>
    subprocess.run("dir")
  File "E:\Users\klo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 472, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "E:\Users\klo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "E:\Users\klo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I'd expect python to run `dir` and give me a list of the folders in the directory

Comment: although after running subproces.call , subprocess.run works now, but it only works when I use "shell=True". Not without it. Is there an explanation for this?

Comment: The explanation is that `dir` is a shell command, not a program. If you use `shell=False` then you are expected to provide the path to an executable and `dir` isn't an executable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dir` is a command in `cmd.exe`, which means you want to do:

```
subprocess.run(['cmd.exe', '/c', 'dir'])
```